# how to delete a new of an object of base class in a derivative class?

Tags: c++, memory, destructor, new-operator

Imagine I have a base class that contains a pointer and a destructor that deletes the pointer.

```cpp
class Base {
private: 
  int *p;
public:
  Base(int data) : p(new int[data]) {}
  ~Base() {delete[] p;}
};
```

And I a have a derivative class that also contains a pointer and has a method in which I make a new of the base class.

```cpp
class Drived: public Base{
private:
  Base* _root;
public:
  Drived(int data) : Base(data), _root(new Base(data)) {}
  ~Drived() {delete _root;}
  void myMethod() {Base* bewBase = new Base(10);}
};
```

So if I do this, I would have a memory leak because in method `myMethod` I do a new and never delete it.
I want to know how I could fix this problem.
Thank you in advanced for helping me.
P.S: the codes in this question are just examples and my not compile properly. i just wanted to show a better vision of my question. Also I know that I can use `std::unique_ptr` for this kind of staff but i really want to learn how to manage this throw raw pointers.

Comment: Regarding the actual question: You ignore the pointer that you `new`ed in `myMethod` completely. What is it supposed to be used for? You must assure that you delete it, e.g. by calling `delete bewBase;` at the end of `myMethod`. But I don't see how this relates to inheritance at all. You are using the base type in the derived class like any other normal type. The additional inheritance to that class is irrelevant for what you wrote.

Comment: Why are you using `Base *`  when `Base` would do just fine ?

Comment: @uneven_markoh sorry. you are right

Comment: @uneven_mark I am asking how I can delete a new of Base class inside a method of Derived class when an object of drived class get delted. I mean how I can delete that new inside destructor of drived class and not in the method body

Comment: If you want to delete the object that you `new`ed when the destructor of `Drived` is called, then you need to store a pointer to the object in `Drived` and call the call `delete` on it in the destructor. @JoseMaria gave you an example of how. Whether the object is of type `Base` or some other type is completely irrelevant to this. Maybe try to explain what you think would be different if `Drived` was not inheriting from `Base`. You may have some misunderstanding of what inheritance does.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question? _"I would have a memory leak because in method `myMethod` I do a new and never delete it."_ So add a `delete` statement to `myMethod`. Problem solved?

Comment: @JaMiT actually I want delete the object created inside the method in the destructor of the class and not in the body of the method

Comment: @uneven_mark but in that case I would have to use an attribut to do that. Is there any other way that I can use?

Comment: @Mohammadreza Your question fails to mention this rather important consideration. It would also be worth mentioning why adding a delete statement to the destructor did not work for you. Take the time to describe your situation. Don't sacrifice clarity for brevity.

Comment: @Mohammadreza Your class currently contains a pointer to a `Base` as data member, which points to the `Base` object that you created in `_root(new Base(data))` and a `Base` subobject as base of the `Drived` object, which is initialized with `Base(data)`. Now you are creating a third `Base` object in `myMethod`. You need to place this object somewhere and maybe remember a pointer to it. So where do you want to place it? If you use `new` like you do it is always placed in some new memory, so you need to remember a pointer to it. The only ways are to override `_root` or add another pointer

Comment: @Mohammadreza If you want to place the new `Base` object that you are creating into the `Base` subobject of the `Drived` class, you first need to destruct the `Base` subobject that is currently placed there and then use a placement-new to put it there. In that case you don't need to retain a pointer to it, because the class knows where its own subobjects are. The destructor of `Drived` would then destruct that new `Base` object automatically. However this is a very unusual technique and there is basically no good reason to do something like this.

Comment: @uneven_mark thank you for information. actually i am implementing a dictionary with trie for an assignment of university and if I show you my code, you will understand what exactly do I mean. I have a Trie class that inherites from a Tree class and have a root that is the type of tree class and I have an insertion method that inserts a word in my trie. and in this method, sometimes I need to do a new inorder to insert a Tree data into the trie and it is there that I don't know how to delete this new

Comment: @Mohammadreza If you have a concrete use case in mind, then you should describe that in the problem and give a short self-contained example of the use case and the problem you are having with it. This seems like an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Drived: public Base{
private:
  Base* _root;
  Base* bewBase;
public:
  Drived(int data) : _root(new Base(data)) {bewBase = nullptr;}
  ~Drived() {delete _root; if (bewBase != nullptr) delete bewBase;}
  void myMethod() {bewBase = new Base(10);}
};
```

or you can reuse _root pointer, and delete the content of _root before new allocation.

Comment: what do you mean reuse _root content??

Comment: "reuse _root **pointer**", if you only need one pointer to Base class, you could do:

void myMethod() {delete _root; _root = new Base(10);}

Comment: Please don't use `NULL`, use `std::nullptr` instead.

Comment: @Frank • `nullptr` is a keyword, so it has no std.  `std::nullptr_t` (in `<cstddef>`) is the `decltype(nullptr)`.